# MVEL Error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mvel2/ConversionHandler

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, owl, mvel

I am having problems with the mvel. I got an error msg after executing my program: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mvel2/ConversionHandler`.

Also other msgs can be found below. Could it be that I have the wrong version of mvel in my pom file? How can I know which is the right version?

I am using Drools: 6.1.0.Final
Mvel: mvel2.4.0.Final

```html
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mvel2/ConversionHandler
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.DefaultConstraintBuilderFactory.<clinit> (DefaultConstraintBuilderFactory.java:6)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.DroolsCompilerComponentFactory.<init> (DroolsCompilerComponentFactory.java:11)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.init (KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:238)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.init (KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:188)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.<init> (KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:153)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages (AbstractKieModule.java:178)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify (AbstractKieProject.java:43)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject (KieBuilderImpl.java:208)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll (KieBuilderImpl.java:177)
    at irobot.RuleE.createKieContainer (RuleE.java:48)
    at irobot.RuleE.createStatelessKieSession (RuleE.java:36)
    at irobot.RuleE.<init> (RuleE.java:23)
    at irobot.Client.main (Client.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mvel2.ConversionHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.DefaultConstraintBuilderFactory.<clinit> (DefaultConstraintBuilderFactory.java:6)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.DroolsCompilerComponentFactory.<init> (DroolsCompilerComponentFactory.java:11)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.init (KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:238)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.init (KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:188)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.<init> (KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:153)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages (AbstractKieModule.java:178)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify (AbstractKieProject.java:43)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject (KieBuilderImpl.java:208)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll (KieBuilderImpl.java:177)
    at irobot.RuleE.createKieContainer (RuleE.java:48)
    at irobot.RuleE.createStatelessKieSession (RuleE.java:36)
    at irobot.RuleE.<init> (RuleE.java:23)
    at irobot.Client.main (Client.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.770 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-25T22:06:21+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project irobot: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: org/mvel2/ConversionHandler: org.mvel2.ConversionHandler -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try to see if you don't have more than 1 version of MVEL in your project. Check if your dependencies are not bringing another version of MVEL that conflicts with the one Drools is using.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: [INFO] |        |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:6.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.kie:kie-internal:jar:6.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.kie:kie-api:jar:6.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.23:compile

Answer (score 0):

This is because the MVEL dependency is missing, try add it from here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mvel/mvel2